# Как создать репозиторий на GitHub заново?

Tags: github

Здравствуйте. Я создал репозиторий для  своего проекта на GitHub. Потом я удалил репозиторий с GitHub. Когда я пытаюсь создать репозиторий заново ("VCS->Import into Version Control->Share Project on GitHub), Intellij IDEA выдает мне "Project is already on GitHub" и не создает репозиторий. Что мне делать?

Comment: @Andrach, я с такой ситуацией не сталкивался, но я бы попробовал создать пустой репозиторий там же, после чего через консоль бы добавил как remote:

    git remote add origin git@github.com:owner/repo.git

И после первого пуша

    git push -u origin master

Все должно пойти как обычно

Comment: Ого, вы вернулись через год, чтобы принять ответ. Круто )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Локальный репозиторий Git (а через него и IDEA) знает, что проект был расшарен на GitHub - настроен remote c адресом на GitHub. Удалите соответствующий ему remote, должно сработать.

```
# Покажет список
git remote
# Вероятно, в списке будет только origin
# Проверить, что это тот самый
git remote show origin
# удалить тот, что на гитхабe
git remote remove origin
# при этом удаляется не сам репозиторий с гитхаба, а локальная ссылка на него
```

После этого пробуйте еще раз через IDEA.